# If the two smallest eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix of a network are equal to zero, then does it mean that the network is not connected?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices, laplacian

What does it mean if the two smallest eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix of a graph are equal to zero?

Comment: That it's disconnected, yes. This is standard in treatments of the subject.

Comment: the multiplicity of the 0 eigenvalue is the number of connected components.

Comment: @user1099798: Perhaps you should ask this question on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "network" you mean "graph", then yes, the eigenvalue 0 having multiplicity at least two means that the graph has at least two connected components. This depends on the fact that the characteristic vector of each connected component is always an eigenvector for the eigenvalue 0.

If by network you mean something different (an oriented graph? perhaps with some weights and/or capacities?), then you should first explain what you mean by "Laplacian matrix" of it.

Comment: This can be best understood by looking at the Matrix-Tree Theorem. If you have a Laplace Matrix with Eigenvalue 0 of multiplicity at least 2, then the determinant of any co-factor of the Laplace matrix is 0, and this means by the Matrix-Tree Theorem that the graph has 0 spanning trees and hence it is not connected.